# InMemory Caching in MVC 5 from a MVC 6 article

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I found this fine article [InMemory Caching for MVC 6](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1246/inmemory-caching-aspnet-mvc-6-core). Is it compatible with MVC 5? Is there any technical issues making it impossible to work in MVC 5?

I'm having trouble with "porting" the References, Services and Dependency Injection:

1)

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

2)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped(typeof(DataAccess));
    services.AddSingleton<IService<Employee>, EmployeeService>();
    services.AddCaching();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

3)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Comment: Since MVC Core 1.0 (formerly called MVC 6 or ASP.NET 5, or ASP.NET vNext) is a completely rewritten framework, it makes sense that most of the documentation doesn't apply to MVC 5. Did you search for [MVC 5 caching documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+5+in+memory+caching)?

Comment: Hey. I searched alot, and I can see I already hit you second link in your search.

I could't add the nuget "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" in my MVC 5 project, which were needed, so I rejected this portal solution.

Instead I have used this Thread Safe Singleton Cache Helper Class "http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32480.a-thread-safe-singleton-cache-helper-class.aspx".
I just implemented it, and made a quick test, and it seems to be good.